# Как передать полезную нагрузку в обработчик Aeron?

Tags: c, замыкания

Я использую библиотеку Aeron. Она предоставляет мне функцию `aeron_fragment_assembler_create`, которая одним из параметров принимает [Callback](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Для примера:

```c
void poll_handler(void *clientd, const uint8_t *buffer, size_t length, aeron_header_t *header)
{
    aeron_subscription_t* subscription = (aeron_subscription_t*)clientd;
    aeron_subscription_constants_t subscription_constants;
    aeron_header_values_t header_values;

    // How to get some_data here?
}

void some_func(int some_data)
{
    aeron_fragment_assembler_create(fragment_assembler, poll_handler, subscription)
}
```

Мне необходимо получить в обработчике `poll_handler` некоторые локальные данные (`some_data`), т.е. мне нужно реализовать замыкание.

Как я могу это сделать?

Comment: на гитхабе уже [ответили](https://github.com/real-logic/aeron/issues/1292)

Comment: @Fat-Zer Да, вижу. Сейчас проверю ответ, переведу на русский и опубликую с примером. Оставлю знания для тех, у кого в будущем появится такой же вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `aeron_fragment_assembler_create` третьим параметром принимает указатель на любую структуру. Необязательно на `aeron_subscription_t`.

Можно создать свою структуру, инициализировать нужными данными и передать указатель на неё. А для удобства можно сохранить в структуре и указатель на `aeron_subscription_t`.

Примерно так:

```c
typedef struct some_data_t {
    aeron_subscription_t* subscription;
    // ...
} some_data_t ;

void poll_handler(void *clientd, const uint8_t *buffer, size_t length, aeron_header_t *header)
{
    some_data_t * some_data = (some_data_t *) clientd;
    aeron_subscription_t* subscription = some_data->subscription;

    // ...
}

void some_func(some_data_t* some_data)
{
    aeron_fragment_assembler_create(fragment_assembler, poll_handler, some_data)
}
```